# can postfix deliver an incoming message to a random recipient from a list?

Tags: postfix

I'd like to have postfix relay incoming email to one of 5 possible recipients in a somewhat random - or at least evenly distributed way.

for example, when a message addressed to help@domain.com arrives at the postfix server, i'd like that message to be related to one of : admin1@domain.com, admin2@domain.com, admin3@domain.com, admin4@domain.com, or admin5@domain.com.

each incoming message would go to one of the adminX addresses and all messages would be load balanced across all 5 evenly(ish).

is that doable?

thanks,

Me

Answer (score 3):

No, postfix can't do that by itself. A procmail filter might help, but why not set up a real ticketing system where you can track progress of issues, share them and make sure things proceed when an admin goes on holiday?

OTRS is a decent ticketing system for smaller environments. Atlassian JIRA is good too, but rather expensive. There are other options too of course :)

Comment: Jira is not a troubleticketing system. I'd suggest [**RT4**](http://www.bestpractical.com/rt/) for the easiest to use and set up.

Comment: Jira is definitely useful as a ticketing system. Or at least my 170000 tickets think so :) I find RT more an exercise in masochism than a ticketing system, though I've not used RT4 yet.

Comment: But it is a bugtracker. It has no sane options to control ticket flows without re-programming the whole damn thing.

Comment: You mean RT4 right? :)

Comment: Argh burble urgh you...you...

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to send to a common address and then program procmail to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with the need to have a real ticket system...if that is what you are trying to do.

That being said, you CAN do this by using a combination of postfix and haproxy. You will need to setup multiple instances of postfix (take a look at the "postmulti" command), one for each user you need to include. You then have each instance send all it's mail to one user (lookup the luser_relay in the Postfix configuration docs.)

Once you have multiple instances setup and running on different posts (all must run on something other than 25), setup haproxy on port 25 and have it load balance between the instances.